# Setting the order of x or y in ggplot by row index (original order of the data) and not by alphabetical order

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I want to plot my data based on their **original order** and not by alphabetical or numerical order (the order from top to bottom should be like variable `d`, variable `a`, variable `c` and variable `b`). My `df` is like below one:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~variables, ~names, ~values,
  'vard', "D", 2.5,
  'vard', "D", 3.5,
  'vard', "D", 4.9,
  'vara', "A", 2.5,
  'vara', "A", 3.5,
  'vara', "A", 4.9,
  'varc', "C", 8.5,
  'varc', "C", 7.3,
  'varc', "C", 6.1,
  'varb', "B", 3.1,
  'varb', "B", 5.2,
  'varb', "B", 7.8
)

df %>% ggplot(aes(x = variables, y = values)) + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_levels <- df$variables %>% unique %>% rev
df <- df %>% mutate(variables = factor(variables, levels = new_levels))
df %>% ggplot( aes(x=variables, y=values)) + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Zhiqiang Wang. I guess I should use parentheses with `unique` and `rev`.

Answer (score 1):

With `{forcats}`, you can use `fct_inorder()` to change the order of the levels by the order in which they first appear, and `fct_rev()` to reverse order of factor levels.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(variables = fct_rev(fct_inorder(variables))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variables, y = values)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another suggestions using `fct_inorder` but without `fct_rev` and without `coord_flip`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = fct_inorder(variables), x = values)) +
  geom_col()+
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev)
```

[image]